Timeout in DryIOC
The Azure function works fine as long as there is not much moch load. Under heavy load I get DryIOC timeouts time and time again. Not always.
How can I enlarge the timeout or where can I call this exception.TryGetDetails(container) as mentioned in the exception text?
---> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.Rpc.RpcException: Result: Failure
Exception: DryIoc.ContainerException: code: Error.WaitForScopedServiceIsCreatedTimeoutExpired;
message: DryIoc has waited for the creation of the scoped or singleton service by the "other party" for the 3000 time ticks without the completion.
You may call `exception.TryGetDetails(container)` to get the details of the problematic service registration.
The error means that either the "other party" is the parallel thread which has started but is unable to finish the creation of the service in the provided amount of time.
Or more likely the "other party" is the same thread and there is an undetected recursive dependency or
the scoped service creation is failed with the exception and the exception was catched but you are trying to resolve the failed service again.
For all those reasons DryIoc has a timeout to prevent the infinite waiting.
You may change the default timeout via `Scope.WaitForScopedServiceIsCreatedTimeoutTicks=NewNumberOfTicks`
at DryIoc.ContainerException.WithDetails(Object details, Int32 error, Object arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3) in /_/src/DryIoc/Container.cs:line 14334
at DryIoc.Throw.WithDetails(Object details, Int32 error, Object arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3) in /_/src/DryIoc/Container.cs:line 14774
at DryIoc.Scope.WaitForItemIsSet(ImMapEntry`1 itemRef) in /_/src/DryIoc/Container.cs:line 13166
at DryIoc.Factory.GetExpressionOrDefault(Request request) in /_/src/DryIoc/Container.cs:line 11010
at DryIoc.Container.ResolveAndCache(Int32 serviceTypeHash, Type serviceType, IfUnresolved ifUnresolved) in /_/src/DryIoc/Container.cs:line 426
at DryIoc.Container.System.IServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType) in /_/src/DryIoc/Container.cs:line 344
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance[T](IServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.DurableTask.Worker.Grpc.GrpcOrchestrationRunner.LoadAndRun(String encodedOrchestratorRequest, ITaskOrchestrator implementation, IServiceProvider services)
at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask.DurableTaskFunctionsMiddleware.RunOrchestrationAsync(FunctionContext context, BindingMetadata triggerBinding, FunctionExecutionDelegate next) in /_/src/Worker.Extensions.DurableTask/DurableTaskFunctionsMiddleware.cs:line 58
at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.FunctionsApplication.InvokeFunctionAsync(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\FunctionsApplication.cs:line 77
at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Handlers.InvocationHandler.InvokeAsync(InvocationRequest request) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Grpc\Handlers\InvocationHandler.cs:line 88
Stack: at DryIoc.ContainerException.WithDetails(Object details, Int32 error, Object arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3) in /_/src/DryIoc/Container.cs:line 14334
at DryIoc.Throw.WithDetails(Object details, Int32 error, Object arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3) in /_/src/DryIoc/Container.cs:line 14774
at DryIoc.Scope.WaitForItemIsSet(ImMapEntry`1 itemRef) in /_/src/DryIoc/Container.cs:line 13166
at DryIoc.Factory.GetExpressionOrDefault(Request request) in /_/src/DryIoc/Container.cs:line 11010
at DryIoc.Container.ResolveAndCache(Int32 serviceTypeHash, Type serviceType, IfUnresolved ifUnresolved) in /_/src/DryIoc/Container.cs:line 426
at DryIoc.Container.System.IServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType) in /_/src/DryIoc/Container.cs:line 344
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance[T](IServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.DurableTask.Worker.Grpc.GrpcOrchestrationRunner.LoadAndRun(String encodedOrchestratorRequest, ITaskOrchestrator implementation, IServiceProvider services)
at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask.DurableTaskFunctionsMiddleware.RunOrchestrationAsync(FunctionContext context, BindingMetadata triggerBinding, FunctionExecutionDelegate next) in /_/src/Worker.Extensions.DurableTask/DurableTaskFunctionsMiddleware.cs:line 58
at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.FunctionsApplication.InvokeFunctionAsync(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\FunctionsApplication.cs:line 77
at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Handlers.InvocationHandler.InvokeAsync(InvocationRequest request) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Grpc\Handlers\InvocationHandler.cs:line 88
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.WorkerFunctionInvoker.InvokeCore(Object[] parameters, FunctionInvocationContext context) in /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script/Description/Workers/WorkerFunctionInvoker.cs:line 101
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionInvokerBase.Invoke(Object[] parameters) in /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script/Description/FunctionInvokerBase.cs:line 82
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionGenerator.Coerce[T](Task`1 src) in /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script/Description/FunctionGenerator.cs:line 225
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.InvokeAsync(Object instance, Object[] arguments) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.cs:line 52
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.OutOfProcMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<<CallOrchestratorAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask\OutOfProcMiddleware.cs:line 130
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.TriggeredFunctionExecutor`1.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<<TryExecuteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\TriggeredFunctionExecutor.cs:line 50
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.InvokeWithTimeoutAsync(IFunctionInvoker invoker, ParameterHelper parameterHelper, CancellationTokenSource timeoutTokenSource, CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource, Boolean throwOnTimeout, TimeSpan timerInterval, IFunctionInstance instance) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 581
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithWatchersAsync(IFunctionInstanceEx instance, ParameterHelper parameterHelper, ILogger logger, CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 527
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(IFunctionInstanceEx instance, FunctionStartedMessage message, FunctionInstanceLogEntry instanceLogEntry, ParameterHelper parameterHelper, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 306
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(IFunctionInstanceEx instance, FunctionStartedMessage message, FunctionInstanceLogEntry instanceLogEntry, ParameterHelper parameterHelper, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 352
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.TryExecuteAsync(IFunctionInstance functionInstance, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 108. IsReplay: False. State: Failed. RuntimeStatus: Failed. HubName: rsvceuwreferixitemimport. AppName: rsvc-euw-ref-erixitemimport. SlotName: Production. ExtensionVersion: 2.13.0. SequenceNumber: 49. TaskEventId: -1 ``` 


please share your function code

As the exception message suggests, you may increase the timeout via static scope field Scope.WaitForScopedServiceIsCreatedTimeoutTick.
The same for the exception details. Please read the message. If you do not have access to the container instance you may resolve it as IContainer interface.
Exception: DryIoc.ContainerException: code: Error.WaitForScopedServiceIsCreatedTimeoutExpired;
message: DryIoc has waited for the creation of the scoped or singleton service by the "other party" for the 3000 time ticks without the completion.
You may call `exception.TryGetDetails(container)` to get the details of the problematic service registration.
The error means that either the "other party" is the parallel thread which has started but is unable to finish the creation of the service in the provided amount of time.
Or more likely the "other party" is the same thread and there is an undetected recursive dependency or
the scoped service creation is failed with the exception and the exception was catched but you are trying to resolve the failed service again.
For all those reasons DryIoc has a timeout to prevent the infinite waiting.
You may change the default timeout via Scope.WaitForScopedServiceIsCreatedTimeoutTicks=NewNumberOfTicks

